# MS Access count the number of items in stock from a history table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that has a history of all changes in the serial code
of each product.

**tableHistory**

```
id date        serial available
...............................
1  09/10/2020  1      True     
3  09/10/2020  2      True    
4  09/11/2020  1      False     
5  09/11/2020  2      False     
6  09/12/2020  1      True         
8  09/14/2020  1      False
```

**tableSerial**

```
serial sku  
............
1      100 
2      101
```

I have to count the number of serials in stock for
a given date. Let's say I want to count the quantity for date '09/13/2020'.
I expect to get:

```
sku    quantity
............
100    1 
101    0
```

I tried

```
select t3.sku, count(*)
from ((tableHistory as t1
left join  tableHistory as t2 on t1.serial = t2.serial and t1.id < t2.id)
inner join tableSerial as t3 on t1.serial = t3.serial)
where t2.date is NULL and t1.date<=cdate('09/13/2020') and t1.available = True
group by t3.sku
```

but this code only works for the most recent date. I couldn't find a way to
filter the query before the join.

Comment: Can you explain a little about the purpose of the `available` field in the `tableHistory`?

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: Also can you explain how you calculate your stock? From the sample provided it's not clear how you come to the `quantity` field value.

Comment: @jbud `available` means that the given serial number is in stock. `available = False` means that product X was sent to the customer so it is not available in stock. To calculate the stock we count all the serial numbers that are available for a given date. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try:

```
SELECT 
    tableSerial.sku, 
    Sum(IIf([available], 1, -1)) AS quantity
FROM 
    tableHistory 
INNER JOIN 
    tableSerial 
    ON tableHistory.serial = tableSerial.serial
WHERE 
    tableHistory.date <= #9/13/2020#
GROUP BY 
    tableSerial.sku;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to sum, not count:

```sql
SELECT 
    tableSerial.sku, 
    Sum(-1 + 2 * Abs([available])) AS quantity
FROM 
    tableHistory 
INNER JOIN 
    tableSerial 
    ON tableHistory.serial = tableSerial.serial
WHERE 
    tableHistory.date <= #9/13/2020#
GROUP BY 
    tableSerial.sku;
```